# mysql to compare two timestamp and update next column using trigger

Tags: mysql

I have below mysql table,

```
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| id       | s_time              | e_time              | t_time         |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| 1        | 2016-06-08 09:29:40 | 2016-06-08 09:12:47 | 00:00:00       |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

I want to update t_time column automatically by subtracting (e_time - s_time) when e_time column update happened.

Using `select timediff('2016-06-09 11:00:23','2016-06-09 10:33:59')` was able to get the difference but not sure to how to make this update happened automatically when e_time update happened.

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_update.php

Comment: I am still struggling to form the Mysql command to create trigger. Can someone provide me exact trigger command please